# I wanted to re write a SQL statement which uses 'NOT IN' to join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table1

```
id   name  new_location  old_location
1    adb   fgh           ghj
2    cde   ghj           yth
3    fas   dcq           tm1
4    fas1  tm1           hgy
```

Table 2

```
id     name   new_location  
1      adb    fgh         
2      cde    ghj
3      fas    dcq      
4      fas1   tm1
```

the old location for few person is the new location for some person

```
select t1.* 
from #table1 t1 
where t1.old_location not in (select t2. new_location from table2 )
```

```
id   name  new_location  old_location
2    cde   ghj           yth
4    fas1  tm1           hgy
```

How to re write using join?
please help

Comment: I could easily write this for you but then you won't learn anything. Check out this link, give it a shot. http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/

Comment: why does the title say `not in` when this isnt present in the Sql statement given?

Comment: That is my bad .. meant to say NOT IN   select t1.* from #table1 t1 where t1.old_location not in
(select t2. new_location from table2 )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `JOIN`, just use `JOIN` and set the condition `t1.old_location = t2.new_location` from  `in` subquery.

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1 
INNER JOIN  table2 t2 ON  t1.old_location = t2.new_location
```

---

**EDIT**

but from your expected result your sql seem to need to use `NOT IN` instead of `in`, if you want to `NOT IN` to `JOIN`

you can try to use `OUTER JOIN` then get  `t2.new_location IS NULL`, Which mean the value didn't match with `table1`

```
create table Table1(
   id int,
   name varchar(50),
   new_location varchar(50),
   old_location varchar(50)
);


insert into Table1 values (1,'adb','fgh','ghj');
insert into Table1 values (2,'cde','ghj','yth');
insert into Table1 values (3,'fas','dcq','tm1');
insert into Table1 values (4,'fas1','tm1','hgy');


create table Table2(
   id int,
   name varchar(50),
   new_location varchar(50)
);


insert into Table2 values (1,'adb','fgh');         
insert into Table2 values (2,'cde','ghj');
insert into Table2 values (3,'fas','dcq');      
insert into Table2 values (4,'fas1','tm1');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  t1.*
FROM    table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
        table2 t2
ON  t1.old_location = t2.new_location  
WHERE   t2.new_location  IS NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb1e34/10/0)**:

```
| id | name | new_location | old_location |
|----|------|--------------|--------------|
|  2 |  cde |          ghj |          yth |
|  4 | fas1 |          tm1 |          hgy |
```

Comment: @PEL1 no problem glad to help, you can mark this answer if that help you

Answer (score 0):

This is a requirement that I have to code around all the time.  In particular we have a lot of data, and lists of exceptions. E.g. a table of Products you cannot see.  Depending on how many rows you have left joining to the second table  and then selecting where a field is null can turn out to be very inefficient.

It can make far more sense to add all your results to a temporary table and then delete from that using a join.  I'd code both methods and then evaluate which is the quicker.  On a small number of rows then there's almost no impact at all.  Dependant on your data, it may be a large difference.  Also check the execution plans of both.

Getting it to work is only 10% of the problem - getting it to work quickly is the rest.